# Apply arrayfun on function that needs row of the matrix

Tags: matlab

I have the following code:

```
function y = f(x)
     y = some_black_box_function_that_takes_only_one_row_at_once(x)
end

x = magic(15);
y = zeros(1,15);
for i = 1:15
    y(i) = f(x(i,:));
end
```

I want to get rid of the loop for paralleling purpose. I want use something like `arrayfun` except it should be applied to each row of the matrix not to each element of it.

How can I achieve this in MATLAB?

P.S. Editing `some_black_box_function_that_takes_only_one_row_at_once` to accept 2D matrix is not an option.

Comment: As reported several times, then `arrayfun` is just a hidden for-loop. Typically a standard for-loop is actually faster than using `arrayfun` as the JIT can more easily optimise it. If you want to parallelise use `par for`

Comment: To add to Nicky's comment, you will likely *not* see an improvement with *parfor* for such a small task due to the overhead required for the configuration of the workers.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Actully I am heading towards GPU Parallelism. Furthermore, my array is huge and the function is expensive.

Comment: Have a look at the documentation https://se.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/run-element-wise-matlab-code-on-a-gpu.html, then you will see "You can run your own MATLAB function of __element-wise__ operations on a GPU".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To call a function on a series of non-scalar arguments rather than each scalar element of an array as `arrayfun` does, use `cellfun` instead.

To extract each row from a matrix into cells that `cellfun` can pass as arguments to your function, use `num2cell` along dimension `2`; i.e.:

```
y = cellfun(@some_black_box_function_that_takes_only_one_row_at_once, num2cell(x,2));
```

I'm not aware of any sense in which this actually facilitates parallelisation as is your stated intent, but inasfar as the code in the question is not satisfactory and the solution must take the requested form, this is how you would do it.

Comment: Thank you very much. Yes that answers my question. However, as you stated, it does not utilize the GPU. Typical XY problem. I will open another question. Thanks again!